# Error creating session [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client after I hit callback endpoint implementing Oauth

Tags: header

I have implemented Oauth2 google-strategy in my backend server
we have two endpoints in it one is `/auth/google` which redirect to google login page
and another for callback which is
`/auth/google/callback`

> but the problem is as soon as I hit callback endpoint I am getting Error creating session: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Code if needed

```
this.router.get(`${this.path}/auth/google/callback`, (req, res, next) => {
      passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }, async (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error during Google OAuth callback:', err);
          return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
        }
         
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
        }

        try {
          await this.createSession(req, user);
          await saveOrUpdateUser(profile);
          console.log(user)
          return res.redirect('/dashboard'); 
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error creating session:', error);
          return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
        }
      })(req, res, next);
    });
  }

   
private async createSession(req: Request, user: User) {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    req.login(user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error creating session:', err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
}

public async saveOrUpdateUser(profile:any):Promise<User>{
    try{
       const existingUser = await UserModel.findOne({googleId:profile.id ,email:profile.email})

       if (!existingUser) {
        // If the user already exists, update the user's profile information (if needed) and save the changes.
        const newUser = new UserModel({
            name: profile.displayName,
            email: profile.emails?.[0].value || '',
            googleId: profile.id,
            picture: profile.photos?.[0].value || '',
          });
  
          await newUser.save();
  
          return newUser;
      }else{
        return existingUser;
      }
    }catch(err){
        throw new Error('Error saving/updating user in the database.');
    }
}
```

Hope anyone can help me , thanks !

tried everything I can
wanted to fix this